# Cannot install Python secrets package

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have few dependencies in a project listed in the `requirements.txt` file,

```
requests==2.18.4
secrets==1.0.2
PyYAML==3.12
```

I wanted to installed them and called the command inside the `virtualenv`,

```
$ pip install -r bin/requirements.txt
```

I get the message provided below,

```
Collecting requests==2.18.4 (from -r bin/requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/49/df/50aa1999ab9bde74656c2919d9c0c085fd2b3775fd3eca826012bef76d8c/requests-2.18.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting secrets==1.0.2 (from -r bin/requirements.txt (line 2))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement secrets==1.0.2 (from -r bin/requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for secrets==1.0.2 (from -r bin/requirements.txt (line 2))
```

Inside the `virtualenv`, I can have the versions provided,

```
$ python -V
Python 3.7.2


$ pip -V

pip 19.0.3 from /Users/chaklader/PycharmProjects/Welance-Craft/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Whats the issue here?

**Update**

I had to delete the `secrets` and update the other dependencies:

```
requests==2.21.0
PyYAML==3.13
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there is a [secrets package](https://pypi.org/project/secrets/), it’s very old (2012), has only one release, a broken website, and no info. It doesn’t appear to install on Python 2.7 or 3.7.

You may instead be trying to use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) standard library that’s built-in to Python 3.6+. It’s not a package, so you don’t need to install it or add it to your `requirements.txt`, simply `import secrets`. If you need it for an earlier version, there does appear to be an unofficial [backport](https://pypi.org/project/python2-secrets/).

Comment: I start with Python after a long time and this really helps me.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to install the package myself, I get the same error.

However, when searching this package on pypi.org, it seems that the last released version was in 2012 and the link there to the project's homepage leads to an almost completely empty webpage. I would thus assume that this package doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: We use `secrets` for generating the key: `self.upc("security_key", secrets.token_hex(32))`. Do you know if we can use any other packages that can serve the same purpose?  

The project might be little outdated.

Comment: Are you sure you’re not thinking of the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) standard library? It’s not a package, it’s built-in to Python 3.6+.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a backport of the secrets module for Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5 by the name of **[python2-secrets](https://pypi.org/project/python2-secrets/)**. (the name is a bit confusing in my opinion)

Installation:

```
pip install --user python2-secrets
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue recently(2022) and solved this with

```
pip install python-secrets
```

see documentation in https://pypi.org/project/python-secrets/